# How to display Notfications on Android/iOS using @angular/service-worker

Tags: android, ios, angular, push-notification, web-push

I already prepared my Angular App to receive web push messages by subscribing to [`SwPush.messages`](https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwPush#messages)

When a message is received, I can trigger browser desktop notifications with the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification).

On Android and iOS (16.4 RC) the messages are received, but no push notification is displayed.

As I understood, I have to use [`ServiceWorkerRegistration.showNotification()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) because the Notification API is not supported on mobile devices.

(Browser support: [`showNotification`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification#browser_compatibility) vs [`Notification`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification#browser_compatibility))

**Is there a way to access the service worker registration of the angular service worker package? (Or any other method to send a native notification on mobile devices)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access the ServiceWorkerRegistration by using [`navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator):

```js
    this.swPush.messages.subscribe({
      next: (message) => {
        const title = message.Notification.Title;
        const notification = new Notification(title);
        navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then((reg) => {
          if (reg != null) {
            reg.showNotification(title);
          }
        });
      },
      error: (err) => {
        this.messages.push(err);
      },
    });
```